# Creating Trigger With pl/Python on Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, postgres-xl

I am working with postgres-xl  9.5 , it is not supporting triggers. I am trying to write trigger function by using python it should replace

```
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fnx()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a trigger in Postgres-XL, as [the documentation](https://www.postgres-xl.org/documentation/sql-createtrigger.html) says.